# Converting out-of-band DTMF to in-band when call forwarding with <Dial> in Twilio

Tags: twilio, sip, twilio-twiml, dtmf

Is there an option to convert out-of-band DTMF tones to in-band when call forwarding using the Twiml tags  or .
Trying to resolve an issue with destination number only able to handle in-band DTMF tones and our incoming sip calls parses out-of-band tones.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio only supports RFC-2833 DTMF. If you need to do DTMF translation, you would need to have an SBC or SIP Proxy between Twilio and the SIP destination.